# Laravel: Array to string conversion

Tags: laravel

**SettingController.php**

```
public function SendPicture(Request $request) {

  $title = "Picture Purchase";

  $domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

  $email = DB::table('users') - > where('domain', $domain) - > get();

  $content = "$email purchase your picture : ";

  foreach($request - > input('pic') as $key => $value) {
    $content. = "$value".".jpg ";
  }
}
```

> ErrorException in SettingController.php line 373: Array to string
>   conversion

```
line 373: $content = "$email purchase your picture : ";
```

Comment: There is `$email` is collection probably so you can't convert to string like above

Comment: In you SendPicture function dd($email) after and please show that output

Comment: Try $email = DB::table('users')->where('domain', $domain)->value('email');

Answer (score 0):

If you've only one record you can use value method for getting direct string:

```
  $email = DB::table('users')->where('domain', $domain)->value('email');

  $content = $email ." purchase your picture : ";
```

Note : There is a logical error in your each loop too, remove "" from `$value` :

```
foreach($request->input('pic') as $key => $value) {
    $content. = $value.".jpg ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$email` variable have more then one record. If you use `$email` as email address from `users` table then you can follow below code :

$email = DB::table('users')->where('domain', $domain)->first();

$content = $email."purchase your picture : ";

Hope this help for you!!!